# Python and multidimensional dictionaries

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website using selenium and for the most part its going okay. I've now run into a problem... I'm scraping a horse racing website and would like to store my results in a dictionary to use them later. I want something that I can use like this...

print race['WH'][venue][time] and it will return a url that links to that specific race time.

I have the venues, times and url's being scraped and can print them in sequence etc. Here is what I have so far

```
    for meet in meetings:
    if meet.get_attribute('class') == 'bold':
        venue=meet.text
        #race['WH'] = venue
        #print '{id} - Venue: {venue}'.format(id=i, venue=venue)
        race['wh'][venue] = ' '
    else:
        try:
            anchor = meet.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            text = anchor.text
            link = link = anchor.get_attribute('href')
            #print 'link: {rid}, Time: {text}'.format(rid=r, link = anchor.get_attribute('href'), text = text)
            tim[venue][text] = link
            race['wh'] = tim

        except NoSuchElementException:

            pass  # Are you worried if something is neither a title (bold) nor contains an anchor?
   # race['WH'][venue] = list
print race['wh']['Ayr']
```

Basically the script goes through the  tags and if it finds an element with the class bold, it knows its a venue. Then it try's to find the corresponding race times under each venue (which it does). But I cannot for the life of me get it into a format such as race['WH'][venue][text], I would like to be able to call that to find out the url of that specific race. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the access pattern will use a certain sequence of keys (like venue --> time, so you never need to do time --> venue) the easy answer is to have dicts within dicts.

Simplified example:

```
data = dict()
data['venue1'] = dict()
data['venue1']['time1'] = 'something'
print data
```

In other words: there is no such thing as a multi-dimensional dictionary. You can however nest dictionaries, and this works well as long as you don't have to vary which keys are used to access entries in the dictionary. You would use a very different approach if you needed to use different keys in different situations (more like a database query).

Comment: You are a life saver! The solution was simple and under my nose, just needed someone to say it! Works like a charm. Thanks